# can anyone explain what bazel coverage report details are?

Tags: code-coverage, bazel, lcov

can anyone explain what DA, LH and LF means in this report and what are each numbers?

bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat

```
TN:
SF:src/services/guava/keys/keys.go
DA:16,1
DA:17,1
DA:18,1
DA:19,1
DA:20,0
LH:83
LF:109
end_of_record
```

Comment: output_path=$(bazel info output_path) && genhtml "$output_path"/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat -o coverage_report

Answer (score 0):

The best source I know of for how to parse that is the [`geninfo` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/geninfo).